# @Autowired annotation is not working properly with spring 

Tags: rest, maven, autowired

I have a Restful design for my Maven project, a domain layer with a user class, a data layer with the services with CRUD functionality and a web layer with the controller classes. But when I run the project I get the errors below:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
........
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)   


root cause

   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested              
   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: ........service.UserService org.
   bk.samples.mvc.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [se. 
   datalayer.guards.service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency 
   annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) ..........

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: .........service.UserService 
org.bk.samples.mvc.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type 
[se.datalayer.guards.service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency 
annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}   ..........

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [.........service.UserService] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793) .......
```

Then I removed the `@Autowired` annotation but got the error below:

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

    root cause

    java.lang.NullPointerException
        org.bk.samples.mvc.UserController.allUsers(UserController.java:32)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)..........
```

My `userController` class is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class UserController
{
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/users", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView allUsers()
    {

    ModelAndView mvd= new ModelAndView();
    Collection<User> allUsers= new ArrayList<User>();
    allUsers= userService.findAllUsers();
    System.out.println(allUsers);
    mvd.addObject("allUsers", allUsers);
    return mvd;   
    }
}
```

I don't know what caused the problem and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I am not sure how it is a maven issue. Annotations are not looked at during compile time, rather run time. This error is mainly saying that you do not have a dependency artifact that has the `UserService` class defined in it.

Comment: Take a step back--that you tried simply removing the annotation and still expected things to work sounds like you're not familiar with the environment you're working in. Please tag with Spring; Maven had nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: It's not a maven issue but I need help if anyone can help me I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Maven. You have problems with your Spring configuration. It's telling you that you have no Spring bean of type UserService defined, so it can't create your controller bean, since it depends on having a UserService (as expressed through the @Autowired annotation). You might want to have a look at an [overview of the Spring container](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) and/or the [Spring MVC framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

Comment: Ok,maybe the title is not that good but, can anybody help me to figure out the problem?

Comment: I answered your question: you have no UserService bean available to inject into your controller. In addition, the material that I linked will help you figure out the problem by helping you understand how your project works.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you have spring misconfigured in your webapp and has nothing to do with maven.  Wherever you are bootstrapping spring you are probably including your webapp config but not your data layer spring beans.

Comment: Hi to everyone.  I didn't sad anything about maven and the problem is maven issue. I Just asked what cause the problem and what can it depends on and so on. When I'm using the main method it's working fine but not with controller.

Comment: If you don't believe maven is part of the problem then you should probably remove the maven tag from the question, that's what made us think you were looking at maven as the cause.  As for solving the problem, it still sounds like a spring configuration issue.  You are missing something in your application context configuration in the webapp, so look at where you define your userService bean and make sure it's included in the spring config for your webapp.